# Make a persistent server connection in flutter without an authorization token

Tags: sql-server, flutter, http, server

I am working on a flutter application which connects to a Microsoft server. This server isn't configured for bearer-token authentication, but requires credentials to access both through the browser and through my app. I am trying to write an authentication method that takes a username and a password, then uses a PHP script that I have on the server to authenticate against the stored usernames and passwords. I know that the PHP and server side authentication works. The issue is that I can't seem to send both my server-access credentials, and the credentials that need to be checked, at the same time. Because I can't gain a token-based access, I need to send the username and password for server access every time I make a request, but then the post request isn't read into the php properly. I want to know if there's any way to make a persistent, open connection to the server or the php script, so that I can then send the credentials that need to be authorized through, and get the authentication results from there. Any help is very much appreciated, I'm a junior in university and this is beyond the scale of anything I've ever worked on, and I have no other programmers in the company to go to for support, as I am quite literally entirely on my own.

I tried to just make a request with my server credentials, see if that returned a successful message, and then make another request with the credentials that had to be checked as a post, but this obviously wouldn't and did not work, as the original connection did not remain open.

Comment: Your web server (PHP here) should be configured with the credentials to access the SQL Server.

Comment: My issue though is that I need credentials to even access the php in the first place.